# Differences between TreeNode and TreeNode[]?

Tags: c#, treenode

I´m a newbie, and I can´t view the difference between TreeNode and TreeNode[] the error that returns is

```
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode[]' to'System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode'
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Spring!

Comment: why minus this? if you are new to C# (or programming in generel) it is not ovious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TreeNode and TreeNode[] are different. TreeNode is a single Node while TreeNode[] is an Array of TreeNode.

ForExample:

`TreeNode(String, TreeNode[])` it is an overridden constructor of TreeNode.

```
public TreeNode(
    string text,
    TreeNode[] children
)
```

You can not directly cast TreeNode[] to TreeNode but via calling a single through index.

Answer (score 4):

`TreeNode[]` is array of `TreeNode` type elements. You can see more about [Array at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

`TreeNode` means "one TreeNode object". `TreeNode[]` means "a collection (Array) of Treenodes"

```
   `TreeNode t = new TreeNode()`
```

where as the array must look something like this:

```
    TreeNode[] ary = new TreeNode[1];
    ary[0] = new TreeNode();

    //and vice versa

    TreeNode t = ary[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

The `[]` indicate that it is an array, that is a collection of Treenodes...

Answer (score 1):

The brackets[] denote an array. It seems that your method returns an array of TreeNode-objects, but you are only assigning a single TreeNode-object.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed what Habib says. The [] indicates it is an [array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) the error that is returned says something about the fact that you try to put an Array of TreeNodes into a single TreeNode. This cannot be doen.

If you do something like this

```
TreeNode[] nodes = new TreeNode[2]() {new TreeNode(), new TreeNode()}
TreeNode node = nodes[0] //This will put the first TreeNode from nodes in the node
```

I hope this helps